# Does "3B+ onwards" include 3A+?

Tags: hardware, poe

I want to buy the following (emphasis mine) for my 3a+

> The official Power over Ethernet (PoE) add-on board for the Raspberry
>   Pi. Use this HAT to power a Raspberry Pi via an Ethernet cable,
>   removing the need for a separate power supply, an ideal solution for
>   embedded and IoT projects. For **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and onwards**, an
>   802.3af compliant POE injector, switch or router device is required (not included).

I am not sure A follows B in this case. Does this device work for a Pi 3A+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official power over ethernet HAT will not work on the Pi3A+. The Pi3A+ does not have the ethernet connection nor the 4 pin connector that passes through the ethernet power.